# How to prevent brew to install curl package?

Tags: macos, curl, homebrew

The 'curl' provided by brew doesn't work well with my proxy and I would like to just use system provided one.

How could I let brew know "never try to install curl"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Homebrew will force use a new version but not the system one, if

- macOS version is less than 10.10, or
- curl version is less than 7.41.0

This is done on purpose to ensure the Curl supports modern HTTPS certificates.

Related source code from homebrew.

```rb
  if [[ "$HOMEBREW_MACOS_VERSION_NUMERIC" -lt "101000" ]]
  then
    HOMEBREW_SYSTEM_CURL_TOO_OLD="1"
    HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL="1"
  fi

  # ...

  # Ensure the system Curl is a version that supports modern HTTPS certificates.
  HOMEBREW_MINIMUM_CURL_VERSION="7.41.0"
  system_curl_version_output="$($(command -v curl) --version 2>/dev/null)"
  system_curl_name_and_version="${system_curl_version_output%% (*}"
  if [[ $(numeric "${system_curl_name_and_version##* }") -lt $(numeric "$HOMEBREW_MINIMUM_CURL_VERSION") ]]
  then
    HOMEBREW_SYSTEM_CURL_TOO_OLD="1"
    HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL="1"
  fi
```

Comment: Thanks @simba. For some reason the modern HTTPS certificates does not work in my environment. My workaround is force link the system `curl` to brew directory and pin the curl version to avoid any upgrade.